# How to trigger COW for string when it doesn't fire automatically

Tags: string, delphi, copy-on-write

I've got a record, [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18807028/with-a-class-operator-is-an-implicit-typecast-to-itself-allowed) for background info.

```
TDigits = AnsiString;  //Should be `= array of NativeUInt`, but string has COW

TBigint = record
  Digit: TDigits; // Unsigned number, LSB stored in D[0], MSB in D[size-1]
  Size: Byte; // Mininum = 4, maximum 127.
  MSI: Byte; // Most significant (native)integer minimum=1, maximum=127
  Sign: Shortint;
  class operator Implicit(a: Integer): TBigint;
```

**Background**
I'm using a bignum class that (almost) works like normal integers.
So `a:= 1000000*10000000*12000000*10000000*1000000;` yields perfectly useful results.
For this purpose I use a record with `class operators`.
These trigger automatic type conversion and initialisation.
**Except** when there is no conversion, because I'm assigning a `TBigint` to another `TBigint`.

**The solution**
Use an Ansistring to store the core data, it's got copy-on-write and will clone itself when needed.

**The problem: *(COW does not work if Delphi does not know you're altering the string)***
I've got a few pure assembler routines that manipulate the Digit `dynamic array` disguised as `Ansistring`.

However when I do something like this:

```
Label1.Caption:= BigintToStr(b);
..... this fires:

function BigintToStr(const X: TBigint): AnsiString;
var
  ..
  LocX:= x;   <<-- assignment, locX and X are joined at the hip.
  repeat
    D := DivBigint(LocX, 1000000000, LocX); <<-- this routine changes LocX
                                 ^^+-- but assembler routines bypass COW
```

`X` and `LocX` are joint at the hip, whatever happens to one happens to the other.
Clearly Delphi does not know that the asm routine `DivBigint` is changing `LocX` and therefore a COW is in order.

**The workaround**
If I change the routine to:

```
function BigintToStr(const X: TBigint): AnsiString;
var
  ..
  LocX:= x;
  LocX.Digit[2]:= #0;  <<-- inconsequential change to force COW.
  repeat
    D := DivBigint(LocX, 1000000000, LocX);
```

Delphi gets all clued up and performs just fine. 
`LocX` and `X` are unlinked and everything works fine.
However I don't want to be making silly changes in the middle of some empty space.

**Is there a decent/proper/offical* way to force trigger COW in strings?**
Something like a system call perhaps?

<sub>*circle your favourite option *(with a handdrawn circle)*</sub>

Comment: [`UniqueString`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.UniqueString)?

Comment: Funny enough UniqueString cannot be located, but SetLength(Length(AString)) does the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every method that mutates the buffer should, before performing the modification, call [`UniqueString`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.UniqueString).

> Ensures that a given string has a reference count of one.

In fact, this detail was supplied by [Craig Young's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18807028/with-a-class-operator-is-an-implicit-typecast-to-itself-allowed#comment27826025_18810399) to my answer to your earlier question.

If you are going to make this viable you are going to need to hide the buffer. Make it strict private. That means that you can only access it from methods of your record. And that way you can be sure that anything that modifies the buffer will call `UniqueString`.

Personally, I think that a better solution would be to make the type immutable.

Comment: I see, just to get this straight I call `UniqueString` when I init the record. Any assignment afterwards will then force a copy. Is that how it works?

Comment: If you modify the string using the `[]` operator then you don't need to call `UniqueString` ever. However, you will be casting like mad behind the compiler's back. And so any function that mutates the string must first call `UniqueString`. Again, I would choose to make the record immutable.

Comment: I missed the comment BTW.

Comment: Yes, immutable is the better option, I agree.

Comment: But does XE2 support that option, I thought only XE4 and up do or am I mistaken now?

Comment: There's no difference at all between XE2 and XE4 in this regard. The mobile compilers might in the future implement immutable strings. But even in XE4, the iOS string is mutable. You can implement an immutable type yourself quite easily. Implement a static class function on the record type that returns a new value of that type. Make the only functions that modify the buffer return new values as function return values. Perhaps I should do a self-answer, how do I write an immutable type question?

Answer (score 6):

Should be a comment, but need more space...

If you need to call `UniqueString` or equivalent.
You might as well retain the dynamic record.

A quote from the manual:

> Following a call to SetLength, S is guaranteed to reference a unique string or array -- that is, a string or array with a reference count of one. If there is not enough memory available to reallocate the variable, SetLength raises an EOutOfMemory exception.

Note that this behavior even applies when calling `SetLength(Length(myArray));`.
Delphi will make a copy for you and untangle the problem.

So it turns out there is no need for the complication with the AnsiStrings After all, as long as you call SetLength in every method that accepts the record as a `var` parameter.

**Advantages**
This has the added benefit that if you call `SetLength` to expand the array (as happens often) the added space will be zero-initialized. Something does does not happen with the AnsiString.

Furthermore there is no need to bother with size translations because your `array of TXYZ` already knows the size of its elements. When using AnsiString you need to add `* SizeOf(somestruct)` all over the place.

No typecasting is needed, simplifying the code; and in the debugger the data shows up as it is designed.

[image: A mere call to SetLength makes the dynamic array COW]

As you can see the two instances are no longer linked.

Comment: +1 This is quite interesting. This makes it very easy to write mutable copy on write records with powerful operators. I led you on a wild goose chase with `AnsiString`. Sorry for that!!

Comment: Don't worry 'about it. I learned some new stuff and that was helpful in and of itself.

Comment: I'm having some fun right now writing a mutable COW vector class with Double elements. It's a record with operators. Plan to plug it right into my work code base.